# Where does shell "argument files" or "@ files" originate from?

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

[JCommander](http://jcommander.org/#__syntax), a library for adding CLI support to Java based applications, refers to the concept of "argument files" or "@ files" and *the* @ syntax. While I understand the concept, where does it originate from? I couldn't find any other sources, other than more libraries that support this concept as well (but don't refer to real sources).

To summarize, it is a way to organize shell program arguments in a file instead of directly on the command line. Simple example:

```
> program a b c
```

Becomes

```
> program @myfile
```

myfile:

```
# myfile
a
b
c
```

Supposedly this is to work around character limits or define preconfigured program executions.

I would like to refer this concept from my own documentation but not have to point to a handful of libraries as second hand documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While I could not find documentation on the origin of @-files, I would like to share other tools that support this. It is possible that one of the older tools originated the idea.

Feel free to edit this answer and add to the list.

- [gnu gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) (scroll to the bottom) documents the format. Note that gcc supports recursive references.
- [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627) supports @files, and [documents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__BHCJEIBB) the supported format. Javac does not support recursive references.
- [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624) supports @files (and this can be switched off with `--disable-@files`). The supported format is [documented in detail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR-GUID-4856361B-8BFD-4964-AE84-121F5F6CF111).
- [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc-command.htm#JSJAV-GUID-EAAAE17F-E540-42A0-B22B-4D2B2FD3E4D2) supports @files. This is [briefly documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc-command.htm#JSJAV-GUID-EFE927BC-DB00-4876-808C-ED23E1AAEF7D).
- The above-mentioned JCommander library [supports](http://jcommander.org/#__syntax) @files, but the supported syntax is not documented.
- [picocli](https://picocli.info), another library for adding CLI support to JVM applications, also supports @-files, and the supported format is [documented](https://picocli.info/#AtFiles). Recursive references are supported. Picocli also offers a [simplified format](https://picocli.info/#_simplified_format) for compatibility with JCommander.

Related

- [curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) has some options that either take data on the command line or from a file, using the `@` prefix to indicate the option parameter is a file name